# Wildfly error: Could not start http listener

Tags: wildfly-8

I'm new to Wildfly and I hope you guys can help me with this problem:

I'm following [this](http://wwu-pi.github.io/tutorials/lectures/eai/010_tutorial_jboss_setup.html) tutorial on how to Install Wildfly 8 and when I'm trying to execute step 4 I get the following errors:

[image: Error1]

[image: Error2]

I've been googling for a while now and I can't find an answer. I've tryed with JDK 7 and 8, no changes, I'm using admin permissions, I've even tried to download Wildfly again and still no changes.
More experienced co-workers have seen this and don't have a clue about what's going on.
Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: you can find the port who is using 8080 in windows. like netstat -ao find "8080"  or whichever port is configured in standalone.xml.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The tutorial you linked to, has Wildfly configured to use the default port 8080.  Most likely, you have another process or service running which is already using port 8080.  Try to find out what process it is and stop it, or try configuring Wildfly to use a different port.

Comment: How to find another process running at same port??

Comment: Dave said is really true. Change your http port or service running at port 8080. You can change the port from standalone.xml file. In <socket-binding-group> tag you will find http related line. From there just change to other port for e.g 8090. That's it....! Now you will not find that error in your console.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I inadvertedly added an AJP socket binding while using standalone jboss_cli utility:

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/ajp-listener=ajp:add(socket-binding=ajp)
```

This led to an 'already in use' error that doesn't let any app to start and signaled 503 error through an Apache web server.

I deleted the binding:

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/ajp-listener=ajp:remove
```

And then everything worked normally.

Answer (score 0):

try restart the machine or enable IPV6 in the machine, this error will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

Those having the same problem should check who else uses the port 9990 in your Windows system. TCPView is a good tool to find out the guilty of charge. One of possible common causes in this case is NVIDIA Network Service (NvNetworkService.exe).

If that's the case just find it in your Windows services list and stop/disable it. The service itself is responsible for checking for Nvidia drivers updates, so any time you want it back just turn it on manually.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue.After analysis it was found that the SSL port(443 in my case) was creating this issue. I just terminated the processes that were running on 443 and restarted the wildfly and everything worked fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue with wildfly_8.2.1

Port 8080 was also free, so that solution doesn't worked for me.
Try below procedure as it helped to resolve my issue.

add below lines to your server's /etc/sysctl.conf file

net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1

net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1

No restart is required for this solution.